# How to use multidimensional array in twig below we share input field

Tags: twig

How I used this HTML tag with php code in twig.

```
--name="product_option['option_row'][product_option_value]['option_value_row'][pod]['pod_row'][customer_group_ids][]" --

--<?php if (in_array($customer_group['customer_group_id'], $pod['customer_group_ids'])) { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> />--
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`in`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator)-operator for this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_foo"{% if customer_group['customer_group_id'] in pod['customer_group_ids'] %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
```

[fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/m3d4qo)